# Aloglia: Index circle location zone for geo-search

Tags: geolocation, geo, algolia

Is it possible to index a circle zone and make it work with Algolia geo-search.

The only solution I can come with is to index multiples points of the circle like that :

```
"_geoloc": [
  { "lat": 47.279430, "lng": 5.106450 },
  { "lat": 47.293228, "lng": 5.004570 },
  { "lat": 47.316669, "lng": 5.016670 }
]
```

But I think it wont be very accurate unless I have a lot of points. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to index a circle or a polygon as a location.

I'm not an expert of geolocalization in general but I have never came across this. I think a place is always represented as a single couple of coordinates (lat, lng).

I think if you want to index large places, you'll have to increase the radius at search.

Your idea of indexing multiple points makes perfect sense tho.

Comment: I guess if it's my only solution. But it seems like a lot of points for this to be enough accurate

Comment: Real-world example.  I have a Job/Position record, containing a point-location, for which I am seeking job applicants.  Database has stored in it a bunch of JobSeeker/applicant records, each who has specified their location as well as their willing commute distance.  Basically any situation in which the radius varies by data record and is not knowable in advance by the queryor.